# Google Dataflow has delay in stream jobs using Apache Beam and Kafka

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, stream, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to deploy my streaming job on Google Dataflow. I wrote my stream processing task using Python and Apache Beam where messages are consumed from Kafka, then get windowed, and then the result get published to another Kafka topic. The throughput is near 700 messages per second. Kafka is deployed on one VM on GCP and Dataflow connect to it properly and there is no firewall issue. Also Dataflow job and Kafka server are on the same region. I used `streaming=True` option for my pipeline.

The problem is the processing time of the windows have a huge delay (near 43 seconds on average)  and is not real-time at all when running on Dataflow. However I think I don't have the same issue when using direct runner (I am not sure because Beam and Kafka are not working well together on direct runner). I also tested two kinds of Trigger: default and early AfterProcessingTime and the problem is not with the watermark.

The following images show the result of my debug where you can see the delay is huge at first (all messages are processed nearly the same time) and then get decreased and then jump again (see line 82):

[First windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db7Zk.png)

[The following windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8MZB.png)

I think something is get batched in Dataflow but I couldn't find anything.

P.S. I tried writing on BigQuery at first but then I realize that BigQuery may have its own delay when writing so I tried publishing to another Kafka topic.

Comment: Do you use streaming engine? Check https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/streaming-engine. what is the number of partitions you use?

Comment: Yes streaming engine is active. Also I tried increasing the number of partition, still the same problem.